# How would I write a Rails route with a RESTful param in the middle of the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  Let's say I want to write a route to support a URL of the following form

```
/posts/:key/comment
```

and I would like it to route to the "index" action of my posts_controller .  ":key" is not an ID, just an alpha-numeric sequence that I'd like ot access in my method using params[:key].  There are no other methosd in my controller other than index.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do:

```
get "posts/:key/comment", to: 'posts#index'
resources :posts, only: [:index]
```

...then I get:

```
          GET    /posts/:key/comment(.:format)     posts#index
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)                  posts#index
```

Which I *think* is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes definitely . Is there any way to only have the first route you listed (e.g. "GET /posts/:key/comment") and none of the others?